# Python: Neither If nor Else

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, break, turtle-graphics

The strangest thing happened. Its pretty self-explanatory; here it is.

```
for sublist in uses:
    print("for sublist in uses")
    print(uses)
    if (sublist[1] == 2):
        print("sublist[1] = 2")
        count = 1
        break
    else:   
        turtle.exitonclick()
        print("sublist[1] ≠ 2?", uses)
        break
print("*")
```

And this gives:

```
for sublist in uses
[[(-100.00,-0.00), 1], [(0.00,0.00), 2], [(100.00,0.00), 1]]
```

Then it stops. After I click on the Turtle Graphics window again,

```
sublist[1] ≠ 2? [[(-100.00,-0.00), 1], [(0.00,0.00), 2], [(100.00,0.00), 1]]
*
```

Comment: Using the shown data, `sublist[1]` is 1; it looks like `turtle.exitonclick()` pauses until you click.

Answer (score 0):

`exitonclick()` invokes `mainloop()` (Which is like an infinite loop) in tkinter, which will keep the turtle window open until you click anywhere in the canvas. Try switching it to:

```
for sublist in uses:
    print("for sublist in uses")
    print(uses)
    if (sublist[1] == 2):
        print("sublist[1] = 2")
        count = 1
        break
    else:   
        print("sublist[1] ≠ 2?", uses)
        break
print("*")
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first `sublist` in the loop, `sublist[1]` is `1`. At that point you execute the `turtle.exitonclick` which waits for the click; then it prints the expected result. You never get to the second `sublist` because of the `break`.